# SpringBoot microservice How to set properties in application context using java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, applicationcontext

I have a spring-boot microservice with Java based config. Now there is an auth token container, which I need to call to get the access token. That auth token library has a class like this. Notice that the class `AuthServletContextListener` comes from a third party  `jar` file which I can not modify.

```
public class AuthServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        try {
            ServletContext e = arg0.getServletContext();
            Properties config = new Properties();
            this.addProp(config, e, "auth.token.url", "Token Service URL");
            this.addProp(config, e, "auth.system.username", "System Username");
            this.addProp(config, e, "cauth.system.password", "System Password");
            TokenContainer.init(config);
        } catch (IOException arg3) {
            arg3.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private void addProp(Properties config, ServletContext context, String propName, String descrip) {
        String propVal = (String) context.getAttribute(propName);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(propVal)) {
            propVal = context.getInitParameter(propName);
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(propVal)) {
            config.put(propName, propVal);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("error: ");
        }
    }
}
```

The AuthContextListener has an annotation that automatically looks for an application startup event. This automatically starts the container correct settings if the above context params are included. I can then grab the token through that container like this:

```
TokenContainer.getSystemToken()
```

This will initialize successfully if the above context params are included in the web.xml like so:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>auth.system.username</param-name>
   <param-value>UserName</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The same Application context configuration as above can be performed by creating a Spring bean with the following information:

```
<bean>
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="auth.token.url" value="${auth.token.url}"/>
            <entry key="auth.system.username" value="${auth.system.username}"/>
            <entry key="auth.system.password" value="${auth.system.password}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My question is how can I achieve the same using Java based configuration in a latest spring boot application. All I have is `application.yml` file with the auth endpoint, username and password values. I tried using `@Configuration` bean but no luck. How can I set those three props in application context and make that listener start automatically for me.

Comment: Don't use the listener... Just create a class which does the same but as a regular Spring Bean. If you really want to use this create another `ServletContextListener` which exposes the properties in the servlet context and make sure it executes before this listener.

Comment: @Deinum Some auth lib vendor has given me the listener and container as a jar file. So they cache tokens inside the container. So listener is the only hope for me to get there. I have no liberty to change the listener too since it is a jar given by the auth lib vender.

Comment: Why... If you implement the same logic in a regular Spring bean it will still work... You just need to put those 4 lines of code in Spring bean and load the properties from Spring... (But see my answer which should help).

Comment: Ok, will try both of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your application.yml or application.properties add a set for your auth url :

```
#Example for application.properties
auth.token.url = http:\\...
```

Then in your configuration class configure your place holder so then you can read your properties values  :

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
        @Bean
        public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));//or application.yml
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }

    }
```

Then in your AuthServletContextListener classes : add this

```
public class AuthServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Value("${auth.token.url}")
  private String authUrl ;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        try {
            ServletContext e = arg0.getServletContext();
            Properties config = new Properties();
            this.addProp(config, e, "auth.token.url", authUrl);
            this.addProp(config, e, "auth.system.username", "System Username");
            this.addProp(config, e, "cauth.system.password", "System Password");
            TokenContainer.init(config);
        } catch (IOException arg3) {
            arg3.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private void addProp(Properties config, ServletContext context, String propName, String descrip) {
        String propVal = (String) context.getAttribute(propName);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(propVal)) {
            propVal = context.getInitParameter(propName);
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(propVal)) {
            config.put(propName, propVal);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("error: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no control over the `AuthServletContextListener ` class. Which was written by some third party and I just get it via mvn dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-parameters.auth.token.url=<your-value>
server.servlet.context-parameters.auth.system.username=<your-value>
server.servlet.context-parameters.auth.system.password=<your-value>
```

This will expose the values as context parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: I like this solution waiting for your back about it @Ravinda Ranwala